# I created an exception ArrayOutOfBoundsException to overcome I created a file Aiobe but it's not printing the message and it's printing the exception

Tags: java

Employee constructor

```
public Employee[] saves() {
    save();
    Company[] com=save();
    Employee []emp=new Employee[6];
    emp[0]=new Employee(321,"rahul","manager","Male",907374383,City.KODUNGALLUR,com[0]);
    emp[1]=new Employee(654,"akhil","assistant manager","Male",703845983,City.KOZHIKODE,com[1]);
    emp[2]=new Employee(987,"mithun","supervisor","Male",598339834,City.KOCHI,com[2]);
    emp[3]=new Employee(721,"visakh","assistant supervisor","Male",339835300,City.TRIVANDRUM,com[3]);
    emp[4]=new Employee(548,"sharma","trainee","Male",545348945,City.THRISSUR,com[4]);
    
    return emp;
}
```

Function

```
public void exception()throws ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException {
    Company[] com=save();
    Employee[] emp=saves();
    try {
        throw new Aiobe(emp[5]);
    }catch(Aiobe e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Aiobe file

```
public class Aiobe extends Exception{
    private static final String message="Employees 6 does not exist add a employee";

    public Aiobe() {
        super(message);
    }
    public Aiobe(Employee res) {
        super(message);
    }
}
```

Constructor employee contains all the company arrays.i am making a non declared array emp[5]in function.Aiobe is a user defined Exception.I want to print the message inside Aiobe.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: Index 5 out of bounds for length 5
    at com.aitrich.yellowpages.YellowPages.exception(YellowPages.java:130)
    at com.aitrich.yellowpages.Main.main(Main.java:18)
```

The code had exception but now it's handled.

Comment: can you create a smaller (but complete) reproducable example? also: give us the correct error message?

Comment: @Stultuske pls check it correct it

Comment: you don't even provide sufficient information to reproduce the issue, nor do you show the entire error message, withholding relevant information. What do you want me to "correct"?

Comment: Why have you created the `Aiobe` class at all? It's unclear what you're trying to achieve here. But accessing `com[5]` will throw an `ArrayOutOfBoundsException` before you even construct the instance of `Aiobe`...

Comment: your problem is you are trying to access the sixth element of an array that holds only five.

Comment: can you what to do to print exception handler message

Comment: @Stultuske can u tell another method to make an exception.here if i declare the size 6 it will print many other errors in program.can you tell me another one

Comment: you did not declare the size 6. honestly, your entire code makes little to no sense to me

Comment: i did that for employee. thanks to you Stultuske that i corrected the size.Now its okay@Stultuske

Comment: @Stultuske can you help me in latest question that i have uploaded

Comment: check the size of the array, and don't allow your code to go out of bounds

Answer (score 0):

```
public void exception(){
        
    Company[] com=save();
    Employee[] emp=saves();
    try {
        throw new Aiobe(com[5]);
    }catch(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        throw new Aiobe();
    }
}
```

com[5] will throw ArrayIndexOutOfBoundException and you are trying to catch Aiobe exception that is why it is not working.

Comment: its not working i edited the code again pls check

Comment: Edited answer accordingly